# How to get the text from a match till the next match of the same pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

How do I get the text from a match till the next match of the same pattern?

I have a log file like this:

```
INFO1: BLAH
INFO2: BLAH
SOMETHING RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2
SOMETHING DIFFERENT RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2
SOMETHING OTHER WAY RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2
SOMETHING ALSO RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2
INFO1: BLAH
INFO2: BLAH
SOMETHING RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2
SOMETHING DIFFERENT RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2
SOMETHING OTHER WAY RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2
SOMETHING ALSO RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2
INFO1: BLAH
INFO2: BLAH
SOMETHING RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2
SOMETHING DIFFERENT RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2
SOMETHING OTHER WAY RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2
SOMETHING ALSO RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2
```

I can find the 2 first lines but I can't get the other lines till the next match.
So I get just the:
    INFO1: BLAH
    INFO2: BLAH

But I would like extrac groups like this:

```
INFO1: BLAH
INFO2: BLAH
SOMETHING RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2
SOMETHING DIFFERENT RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2
SOMETHING OTHER WAY RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2
SOMETHING ALSO RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2
```

I have tried this:

```
start_exec_ptrn = r'INFO1: .+\nINFO2: .+'
last_exec_start = last_exec_end = 0
for m in re.finditer(start_exec_ptrn, log_content):
    start_exec = m.start()
    end_exec = m.end()
    print start_exec, '-', end_exec
    print log_content[last_exec_end:end_exec]
    last_exec_start = start_exec
    last_exec_end = end_exec
    print 150 * '*'
```

Thanks in advance and sorry by my English!

Comment: so you want the sections based on `INFO1:` and `INFO2:`?

Comment: you want print all the line contains INFO1 or INFO2?

Comment: ``re.split(r'(INFO1: .*\nINFO2: .*\n)', stuff)``?

Comment: Exactly @PadraicCunningham. I want to extract the entire section to pass it to a function that will be able to work with it.

Comment: So can we just consider INFO2: As the delimiter or can it appear not preceded by INFO1?

Comment: Here is the real problem I'm facing https://regex101.com/r/sQ8cT9/1
In this link I match just the "delimiter". But what I really need get is the text starting at the delimiter till the last line before the next match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
>>> import re
>>> separator = "INFO1: BLAH\nINFO2: BLAH\n"
>>> map(lambda(p): "%s%s" % (separator, p), re.split(r'%s.*' % separator, all_text)[1:])
```

This returns exactly what you are looking for:

```
['INFO1: BLAH\nINFO2: BLAH\nSOMETHING RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2\nSOMETHING DIFFERENT
 RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2\nSOMETHING OTHER WAY RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2\nSOME
THING ALSO RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2\n', 'INFO1: BLAH\nINFO2: BLAH\nSOMETHING RELATE
D TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2\nSOMETHING DIFFERENT RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2\nSOMETHING O
THER WAY RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2\nSOMETHING ALSO RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2\n'
, 'INFO1: BLAH\nINFO2: BLAH\nSOMETHING RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2\nSOMETHING DIFFEREN
T RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2\nSOMETHING OTHER WAY RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2\nSOM
ETHING ALSO RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2\n']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with lookahead and `re.split` [like this](https://regex101.com/r/dE7rC5/1).

```
(?=INFO1:)(?!\A)
```

or with `re.findall` and flags `re.DOTALL`

```
(INFO1:).*?(?=\1|$)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without regex

```
with open('file.log') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

matches, headers, sec = [], [], []
for i, line in enumerate(data):
    if not line:
        continue
    line_lower = line.lower()
    if line_lower.startswith('info'):
        if not data[i - 1].lower().startswith('info'):
            if headers and sec:
                matches.append({'headers': headers, 'matches': sec})
            headers, sec = [], []
        head = line_lower.split(':')[0]
        headers.append(head)
        continue
    if any(x in line_lower for x in headers):
        sec.append(line)
print matches
#[{'headers': ['info1', 'info2'], 'matches': ['SOMETHING RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2', 'SOMETHING DIFFERENT RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2', 'SOMETHING OTHER WAY RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2', 'SOMETHING ALSO RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2']}, {'headers': ['info1', 'info2'], 'matches': ['SOMETHING RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2', 'SOMETHING DIFFERENT RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2', 'SOMETHING OTHER WAY RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2', 'SOMETHING ALSO RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2']}]
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve all the line if contains INFO1 or INFO2 the regex pattern should be this:

```
^.*\b(INFO1|INFO2)\b.*$
```

Hople helped you!

Comment: Thaks. But I want all the lines form INFO1: BLAH till the last character before INFO1: BLAH again.

Comment: So you want to split your log into: all about INFO1 and after all about INFO2, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

How about just use `split()`?
Assume you assign the text to `string`, you can do like this:

```
separator = "INFO1: BLAH\nINFO2: BLAH"
result = ''.join(string.split(separator)[1]) 
print('{0}\n{1}'.format(separator, result)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the sections always start with `INFO`, you can use groupby:

```
from itertools import groupby

with open("in.txt") as f:
    grps = groupby(f, key=lambda x: x.startswith(("INFO1:","INFO2:")))
    for k,v in grps:
        if k:
            print("".join((v)) + "".join((next(grps,["",""])[1])))
```

Output:

```
INFO1: BLAH
INFO2: BLAH
SOMETHING RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2
SOMETHING DIFFERENT RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2
SOMETHING OTHER WAY RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2
SOMETHING ALSO RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2

INFO1: BLAH
INFO2: BLAH
SOMETHING RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2
SOMETHING DIFFERENT RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2
SOMETHING OTHER WAY RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2
SOMETHING ALSO RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2

INFO1: BLAH
INFO2: BLAH
SOMETHING RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2
SOMETHING DIFFERENT RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2
SOMETHING OTHER WAY RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2
SOMETHING ALSO RELATED TO THE INFO1 AND INFO2
```

Answer (score -1):

You should check findall() call for the string

```
  ## Suppose we have a text with many email addresses
  str = 'purple alice@google.com, blah monkey bob@abc.com blah dishwasher'

  ## Here re.findall() returns a list of all the found email strings
  emails = re.findall(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', str) ## ['alice@google.com', 'bob@abc.com']
  for email in emails:
    # do something with each found email string
    print email
```